# Starting a service as userA from userB by using shell script

Tags: linux, shell, unix, terminal

Is there any way to start a service as userA from userB by using shell script, where userA and userB doesn't have root access. Both the users are password protected.

Comment: If `ssh` is installed, there are ways for A to login/issue commands as B, or vice versa, provided some setup in advance to allow it (which usually implies that this is occurring with permission).  If you are wondering if it is possible without permission, that is more of a security question.  It isn't supposed to be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The usuasual approach for this is to make use of 'sudo':

```
sudo -u userB service whatever start
```

sudo is available out of the box on most linux systems. You can also configure it, so that userA doesn't need to enter a password to use the above command.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.cyberciti.biz/open-source/command-line-hacks/linux-run-command-as-different-user/

Here a resource that shows a few different ways of achieving this.

It looks like `runuser -l  userNameHere -c 'command'` is what you're looking for

Answer (score 0):

If you have ssh setup, you can setup a "no password" login  between the 2 user ids. You can set it up either in a uni-directional manner or a bidirectional manner.

Then you can use ssh to execute a command as another user

```
ssh user@host remote_command
```